# Why is getParentLogger needed in jdbc?

Tags: java, logging, jdbc

Why is this method part of the JDBC API? Why would the user need the parent logger of all the loggers of the JDBC? If JDBC has its own logging system, I do not understand why the user should have the parent logger. For what purpose? Is it necessary to implement?

Comment: To configure it.  Some drivers are obnoxiously verbose even at level INFO, to the point where I turn them off:   `driver.getParentLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);`  And yes, a Driver must implement it.

Answer (score 3):

The method was added in JDBC 4.1 / Java 7 as JSR 221 maintenance release 1.  The specific rationale for the addition is not included in the document that lists the changes: [JDBC Maintenance Release 4.1](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr221/221MRapproved.pdf)

The overall rational says:

> *"The goal is to address several specification issues and to provide support for Automatic Resource Management introduced in
> Java SE 7 as well as several minor enhancements requested by the JDBC EG and user community."*

... so my guess is that this was one of the requested minor enhancements.  Presumably, *they* thought that this enhancement was justifiable.

> Why is this method part of the JDBC API?

Because it was requested by someone.

> Why would the user need the parent logger of all the loggers of the JDBC?

Presumably some users did ... otherwise they wouldn't have requested it!  Also, their reasons must have strong enough to convince the JSR principals, even if we don't know what the actual reasons are<sup>1</sup>.

One possible reason is that this allows the application to control logging levels without needing to know fine details of a particular driver's logger hierarchy.

> If JDBC has its own logging system,

It doesn't actually.  The `java.util.logging.Logger` class is provided by Java SE.  A JDBC driver doesn't have to use JUL logging ... or any logging at all.

> ... I do not understand why the user should have the parent logger. For what purpose?

See above.

> Is it necessary to implement?

No.  `Driver.getParentLogger` is an optional operation.  According to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Driver.html#getParentLogger()), a driver can throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` if it doesn't use JUL logging.

---

<sup>1 - You could trawl the archives for the JSR 223 mailing lists to see if there was discussion there.  I'm not interested in doing it for you though.</sup>